# Unable to see Junit cobertura coverage reports in SonarQube

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, sonarqube, cobertura

SonarQube is reporting the following for my project.

```
Unit Tests Coverage 0.0%; Line Coverage 0.0%; Condition Coverage 0.0%
```

It is not able to find the reports which was created immediately before the Sonar scan. I am using Jenkins to launch the SonarQube scan. In fact in the console output I can see the unit tests being executed and the reports saved in the surefire directory.

Below are the relevant logs from the console output.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ earn-promotional-domain ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/jenkins/workspace/earn/surefire-reports

[INFO] [13:50:20.807] Sensor SurefireSensor
[INFO] [13:50:20.807] parsing /var/jenkins/workspace/earn/surefire-reports
[ERROR] [13:50:20.808] Reports path not found or is not a directory: /var/jenkins/workspace/earn/surefire-reports
[INFO] [13:50:20.808] Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] [13:50:20.808] Sensor CoberturaSensor
[INFO] [13:50:20.808] parsing /var/jenkins/workspace/earn/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

I am using SonarQube 5.1.2. Please let me know if any other information is needed that will help to figure out the problem.

Comment: I use JaCoCo but the process should be the same(ish). You need to inject the agent that instrument class (http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) Then you need to trigger the sonarQube analysis. With the result of cobertura (reusing report) or to run the test again. Here the argument i pass in my jenkins build for JaCoCo -Dsonar.binaries=target/classes -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec

Comment: Thanks @drgn! I didn't realize I needed to give the target directory as an argument since I have a different project where I didn't have to give the target directory. The only difference I can see is that in the project that isn't working, there is a lot of sub-projects and due to that there is a lot of subdirectories. Do you think I have to give each folder as a sonar report path?

Comment: Are these sub-project a maven project with their own pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. There is a parent pom at the top level but each sub-project has its own pom file.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off with Jacoco than cobertura. Cobertura has lot of open bugs yet to be addressed.

Also Jacoco provides a aggregator plugin which will aggregate the coverage from all child modules and display a comprehensive coverage.

Jacoco also doesnt require any additional plugin for SonarQube.

Here's a good example of implementing Jacoco:
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Jeel! I was also leaning towards this option. I will try out Jacoco and see if I have better luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to stick with Cobertura rather than moving to Jacoco, you can try this alternative to cobertura maven plugin:

https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura

Here are some advantages this mojo provides:

- it runs tests once (instead of twice with cobertura-maven-plugin)
- it allows you to split coverage (UT / IT / Overall)
- you get rid of the "obsolete" Cobertura plugin for SonarQube

The documentation on the project's page explains how to add converted reports to SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Jeel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469299/1431303) said, you can use an alternative plugin. But if you necessarily must use the cobertura plugin, you can modify it a little bit.

If I understand correctly, the cobertura:check goal forks a current lifecycle, merges a plugin specific configuration (cobertura-maven-plugin-X.X.jar\META-INF\maven\lifecycle.xml) and executes a forked lifecycle to the test phase. After that "check" mojo is executed.

To make cobertura not to fork a lifecycle you can comment <executePhase> tag in a plugin descriptor (cobertura-maven-plugin-X.X.jar\META-INF\maven\plugin.xml) for the check goal.
Additionaly, you have to copy the configuration from lifecycle.xml to your build configuration. For version 2.7 there is only surefire configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${surefire.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/cobertura</classesDirectory>
    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(possibly extending a default lifecycle using [components.xml](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/08/create-a-customized-build-process-in-maven/)  would also work).

In the last step you have to add an execution for the "instrument" goal in the "process-class" phase because it doesn't have a default phase in a plugin descriptor.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>instrument-classes</id>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>instrument</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>check-coverage</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>clean</goal>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```